# Como altero + por %2B

Tags: php

Tenho um forum do meu jogo onde contas com nomes normais (Ex: Biel) entram no perfil normalmente, o link do perfil é por exemplo `...../profile?pr=Biel`.

Mas tem contas que contem um + na frente do nome (+Biel) e no forum não le o +, não abrindo o perfil.

Gostaria de saber como eu faco pro forum ler o + e abrir o perfil. O codigo do perfil é esse:

```
<a href="profile?pr=<?=$oturum_kadi;?>" class="element-menu-principal">
```

Comment: dá uma olhada na documentacao que tem sobre essa funcao do urlencode... https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php eu nao entendi direito quais caracteres um usuario pode ter no seu nickname quando fizer o cadastro no site. Talvez vc colocando um alert quando tiver os simbolos que estao dando problema, indicando pro usuario escolher outro nome sem os simbolos seria menos trabalhoso!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso com [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php)

```
<a href="profile?pr=<?=urlencode($oturum_kadi);?>" class="element-menu-principal">
```

[Resultado](https://3v4l.org/IDEqb):

```
<?php

echo urlencode('+Biel'); // %2BBiel
```

Comment: sao centenas de contas usando o +, n eh so a Biel ksaksk

Comment: é só um exemplo, o resultado vai depender do valor da sua variável

Comment: Se eu quiser alterar o + por %2B entao eu teria que fazer:

Comment: <?php

echo urlencode ( '+'): %2B 

???

Comment: não exatamente, pq nem todos usuário tem o + no início como você comentou.